# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10 [Program finished]

Tags: python-3.x

I wanted to do a list comprehension that can give the square of odd numbers.

But it only works if I put a single number, if I put two or more it gives this error, I already tried using split and researched about this error, but I didn't understand what should be done.

it has to be list comprehension, I want to practice list comprehension, if what I'm trying to do is something you can't do with list comprehension I'd understand, but it's something you can do, then I'm sure that if I don't understand this error now, it will get in the way of my learning.

```
ka=[int(input("g: "))]

xo=[int(v*v) for v in ka if int(v)%2!=0]

print(xo)
```

I expected a list of the square of odd numbers

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple: `int()` assumes that every character in the input string is part of the representation of a single integer number.

```
>>> int('10')
10
```

When, on the other hand, you include other characters, `int()` chokes on them, reporting the same error you saw:

```
>>> int('10 20 30')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '10 20 30'
```

As you already found out, in such cases you need to split the input string on the separator character.

```
>>> '10 20 30'.split(' ')
['10', '20', '30']
```

So now you have multiple strings to be converted in numbers, and you have to use yet another list comprehension to get those numbers, before you can get the squares of the odd ones. I will leave the list comprehension for you to write, since you said you were interested in practicing them.